# Two seperate laravel projects sharing same login authentication

Tags: laravel-5

I have two Laravel projects in which one is a primary project and other is secondary just like some plugin of the primary project.

But I just want include one link of the secondary project in the primary one but it should have authentication of the first one i.e. primary.

One authentication for both laravel projects on a same server.

Any idea...

Comment: just idea, why not sharing the same database on two project?

Comment: saring same database is fine. That works. but same authentication ???

Comment: I have also just seen this, but have never tried it before, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/share-models-between-two-laravel-projects

Comment: In this case i dont want to use git

Comment: ok, just stick to sharing database to start with

Comment: Ok I will see what can I do and let you know

Comment: This can help us create some plugins on top of something which is already there and things can get much easier combining

Comment: sometimes when @maytham says that, he goes off and puts together a masterpiece, be forewarned :>

Comment: Thanks @Drew that is kind of you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a API for your authentication.

Create a REST full webservice and both your project will authenticate with this service.

Comment: Sound like a nice solution, is it some thing you have tried before?

Comment: Yes I have use this approach one of my web application. We use same authentication for mobile app login and two different web application authentication

Comment: Cool, I then I think @sujitprasad will be happy. thanks for sharing.

Comment: haven't started yet creating API's for Laravel projects.. Is API the only way of doing this job done perfectly... I guesed laravel is such a huge framework that it could have even simplified the combination of two seperate projects any ways thanks for your kind information.

Comment: In this approach you don't have to repeat your code again.

Comment: @sujitprasad mean while I found found link and asked in laracast, her is my share, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/same-login-on-two-different-laravel-projects and http://tutsnare.com/connect-multiple-databases-in-laravel/ (maybe this http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections)